# Hide content to specific city using innerHTML.indexOf

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code:

```
if (
document.getElementById('estado').innerHTML.indexOf('São Paulo') != -1) {
    $('body').addClass("esconder");
}
else {
    alert("Não é a cidade");
}
```

It's working well, but what could I do to use more than one city here?

For example, I have 'São Paulo'.

I want to hide the whole site content to visitor from 3 cities (São Paulo, Rio de Janeiro, Mato Grosso).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a class that all 3 cities share?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a list of those words, and use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on it.

```
const cities = ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Mato Grosso"];

if (cities.some(cityName => document.getElementById('estado').innerHTML.indexOf(cityName) !== -1)) {
  $('body').addClass("esconder");
}
else {
  alert("Não é a cidade")
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to set my answer as accepted so other people can easily see that your issue is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical OR `||` operator for each term, or even loop through an array. I think a slightly more elegant solution would be to make use of the [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function:

```
if( document.getElementById('estado').innerHTML.match( /(São Paulo|Rio de Janeiro|Mato Grosso)/ ) ){
    document.body.classList.add('esconder');
} else {
    alert('Não é a cidade');
}
```